# Handling conditional dialog/popup logic in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a page that programmatically shows a popup in a backing bean method. The popup asks the user a Yes/No question, and the subsequent logical path followed is determined by their response. However, whether the popup is shown or not in the first place is conditional. Also, there is additional logic in the original method, outside of the popup logic, that must be completed.

The issue with this is that ADF seems to spin off the popup into another thread, and keeps executing the logic in the original method simultaneously, while waiting for the user's response. However, the desired effect is that the program halts until the user has answered the question in the popup.

I haven't been able to figure out an elegant way to make this to happen. Ideally, I think the solution is to encapsulate the logic that occurs after the popup is shown (or not shown) in the original method, and call it from the popup's action listener if the popup is shown (otherwise call it from the original method). However, the logic to be encapsulated requires the use of some local variables that were set before the popup was shown. There's no way to get these values to the popup's action listener method in order to pass them to the encapsulated logic (aside from creating global static variables in the bean, which seems like a poor solution).

Another idea I had was to bump up the "show/don't show popup" logic to the task flow. However, it seems that doing this for every single popup would make the task flow really complicated.

Is there a better way to do this? It must be a common issue, and it seems that I'm going about it all wrong.

ETA: I have tried setting the popup's ContentDelivery property to "immediate", and the af:dialog component within the popup so Modal is "true". Neither has produced the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be achieved with a server-side web framework.

For ADF, you will have different events for each lifecycle:
1 - popup opening :: popupFetchListener event
2 - click on OK, Cancel buttons ::DialogListener event
3 - hit Esc button :: popupCancelledEvent

You can share data between these events either on pageFlowScope,  or viewScope.
But if you use ADF BC, you may be better off using transient attributes on View Objects.